# how to use required_if validation in Laravel?

Tags: php, json, laravel

I really wish to know how am i supposed to use `required_if` on `JSON`?

I'm still confused about the idea of API but I have to finish my task, I've added the `validation` on my controller but it doesn't work.

```php
public function StoreReqSchedule(Request $request){

    $this->validate([
        'reqtype'=> 'required',
        'startdate' => 'required',
        'enddate' => 'required',
        'reason'=> 'required_if: reqtype,==, Request Day Off',
        'route' => 'required_if: reqtype,==, Request Schedule',
        'actualschedule' => 'required_if:reqtype,==, Change Schedule',
        'changetoschedule'=>'required_if:reqtype,==,Change schedule',
        'swapcrewid'=> 'required_if:reqtype,==,Swap Schedule',
        'swapcrewschedule'=>'required_if:reqtype,==,Swap Schedule',
        'note'=>'required'
    ]);
    // ...
}
```

is this the correct way to use required if?

****EDIT**

Each `API endpoint` consist of this parameter:

1. For Request Schedule:
2. request-type
3. start-date
4. end-date
5. reason (**Mandatory if request type Request Day Oﬀ**)
6. route (**Mandatory if request type Request Schedule**)
7. actual-schedule (Mandatory if request type Change Schedule)
8. change-to-schedule (Mandatory if request type Change Schedule)
9. swap-crew-id (Mandatory if request type Swap Schedule)
10. swap-crew-schedule (Mandatory if request type Swap Schedule)
11. note

those lists above is the task, I'm having difficulties to understand how to write the code for **Mandatory if request type Request Day Oﬀ** and the other mandatory ofc.

> ErrorException: Declaration of
>   App\Http\Controllers\B777Controller::validate($request) should be
>   compatible with
>   App\Http\Controllers\Controller::validate(Illuminate\Http\Request
>   $request, array $rules, array $messages = Array, array
>   $customAttributes = Array) >> this is the error

Comment: ErrorException: Declaration of App\Http\Controllers\B777Controller::validate($request) should be compatible with App\Http\Controllers\Controller::validate(Illuminate\Http\Request $request, array $rules, array $messages = Array, array $customAttributes = Array) >> this is the error

Answer (score 2):

You just need to remove the 'white space' after `==,` and pass `$request` object to the `validate()` method. See below:

```php
$this->validate($request, [
    'reqtype'=> 'required',
    'startdate' => 'required',
    'enddate' => 'required',
    'reason'=> 'required_if:reqtype,==,Request Day Off',
    'route' => 'required_if:reqtype,==,Request Schedule',
    'actualschedule' => 'required_if:reqtype,==,Change Schedule',
    'changetoschedule'=>'required_if:reqtype,==,Change schedule',
    'swapcrewid'=> 'required_if:reqtype,==,Swap Schedule',
    'swapcrewschedule'=>'required_if:reqtype,==,Swap Schedule',
    'note'=>'required'
]);
```

[Demo](https://implode.io/D0azn5)

Comment: and how if there are three type of request type?

Comment: I didn't get you :(

Comment: can i post picture in here? I'm not sure how to explain it :(

Comment: You can't post picture in comments. Better you modify your question or create a new question if it's different than this one.

Comment: would you please check out the edit I've made? thank you so much for your help

Comment: thank you for helping me! but honestly, I followed your code but it still doesn't work. well I'm super newbie at this so i guess I am the one  who did something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think you didnt passed $request object to validate function

```
public function StoreReqSchedule(Request $request){

    $this->validate($request,[
        'reqtype'=> 'required',
        'startdate' => 'required',
        'enddate' => 'required',
        'reason'=> 'required_if: reqtype,==, Request Day Off',
        'route' => 'required_if: reqtype,==, Request Schedule',
        'actualschedule' => 'required_if:reqtype,==, Change Schedule',
        'changetoschedule'=>'required_if:reqtype,==,Change schedule',
        'swapcrewid'=> 'required_if:reqtype,==,Swap Schedule',
        'swapcrewschedule'=>'required_if:reqtype,==,Swap Schedule',
        'note'=>'required'
    ]);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I haven't finished it yet but thank so much for helping me with this! :)